# Texture Painting does not show up in Game view

Tags: texturing

I am new here.

I just got started working with Blender and have been having a great time with it. I sculpted a character, just a static one for now,to see how it all works. I have texture painted it (quickly) but now I cannot figure out how to get it to show up in the game view. Can anyone point me toward a good tutorial that might help me figure out what I am doing wrong? I can see my paint changing in both my 'texture painting' and 'UV mapping' screens, but it just doesn't show in the game view. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Have you assigned the painted texture to an actual material?

Comment: I am not even sure of how to go about doing that.

Comment: Well I am not much into painting myself, but you should save your painted texture as an image file, add a new material to your character object, and assign said image to the material as a diffuse texture, I suppose.